# unsigned long long conflict with uint64_t?

Tags: c++

We use template specialization for some type parameter like

```
class my_template_class<uint64_t M>: public my_template_class_base<uint64_t> {
 ....
}

class my_template_class<unsigned long long,M>: public my_template_class_base<unsigned long long> {
 ....
}
```

This is working perfectly with 64-bit compilation with gcc. While when we try the 32 bit mode, it reports "previous definition" for above two classes.

So `unsigned long long` is the same as `uint64_t` in the 32-bit compilation but not in 64-bit compliation?

The compilation difference is the `CXX` flag `-m32` and `-m64`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Unlikely; I've never seen a system with a 128-bit `unsigned long long`.

Comment: What does uint64_t actually compile to? I don't have GCC handy but you could check the stdint header. Would probably give some clues as to what the compiler actually sees.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that on a 64 bit platform, `uint64_t` is defined as `unsigned long`, and thus does not conflict with `unsigned long long`, while on a 32 bits platform, `uint64_t` must be `unsigned long long`, yielding your error

Comment: @NiBZ wrong. Windows uses [LLP64 model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models), hence even on 64-bit Windows, long is still 32 bits and `uint64_t` must be defined to `unsigned long long`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc As the OP mentioned gcc in his message, I assumed that he was building on an Unix-like platform (which are LP64). Should've mentioned it in my post.

Comment: @NiBZ gcc on Windows will follow Windows model

Comment: Presumably all the `M`'s are typos

Comment: The duplicate question was about _signed_ long, but otherwise essentially the same.

Answer (score 26):

> So `unsigned long long` is the same as `uint64_t` in the 32-bit compilation but not in 64-bit compilation?

Yes.

In 32-bit mode, most likely `long` is 32 bits and `long long` is 64 bits. In 64-bit mode, both are probably 64 bits.

In 32-bit mode, the compiler (more precisely the `<stdint.h>` header) defines `uint64_t` as `unsigned long long`, because `unsigned long` isn't wide enough.

In 64-bit mode, it defines `uint64_t` as `unsigned long`.

It *could* have defined it as `unsigned long long` in both modes. The choice is arbitrary; all that's required is that it has to be a 64-bit type.

In general, each of the integer types defined in `<stdint.h>` is a typedef for some predefined type with the appropriate characteristics. You can't assume that any of them are distinct from the predefined types.

Comment: On Windows `uint64_t` must be defined as `unsigned long long` as long is only 32 bits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: It's been defined as `__uint64` in the past. It's generally unspecified whether two types with identical representation are in fact the same type; the exception being `char` versus `signed char` or `unsigned char` for which it's defined that these constitute 3 types and 2 representations.

Comment: @MSalters: To be clear, all the predefined types are distinct, regardless of their representation. For example, `int` and `long` are distinct types even if they have the same size and representation. If you're referring to types defined in the standard headers, like `int32_t`, you're right.

Answer (score 10):

This is from `stdint.h` for GCC 4.8:

```
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef unsigned long int   uint64_t;
#else
__extension__
typedef unsigned long long int  uint64_t;
#endif
```

So:

> So unsigned long long is the same as uint64_t in the 32bit compliation but not in 64 bit compliation?

Yes.

Comment: Yes, for GCC. Don't assume it's true everywhere. Visual Studio for instance has an unconditional `typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;`

Comment: Wow, this (not your answer but gcc's impl) is just bullshit. This makes uint64_t unusable in many scenarios. What were they thinking?